# Car lane assignment algorithm

Tags: javascript

I have an array of car objects (sorted in ascending order by start) expressed as follows:

```
var cars = [
  {"name": "car0blue", "start": 0, "end": 3},
  {"name": "car1red", "start": 1, "end": 4},
  {"name": "car2yellow", "start": 3, "end": 7},
  {"name": "car3green", "start": 3, "end": 6},
  {"name": "car4purple", "start": 4, "end": 7},
  {"name": "car5grey", "start": 5, "end": 11},
]
```

The start and end describes where the cars are located on an x-axis.

I'm trying to assign the cars to lanes, always striving to put the car in the lowest numbered lane possible without bumping into another car.

**This is the result I'm trying to achive**

[image]

```
carsWithLanes = [
  {"name": "car0blue", "start": 0, "end": 3, "lane": 0},
  {"name": "car1red", "start": 1, "end": 4, "lane": 1},
  {"name": "car2yellow", "start": 3, "end": 7, "lane": 0},
  {"name": "car3green", "start": 3, "end": 6, "lane": 2},
  {"name": "car4purple", "start": 4, "end": 7, "lane": 1},
  {"name": "car5grey", "start": 5, "end": 11, "lane": 3},
]
```

**This is the logic**

To fit into a given lane the start value has to be greater than or equal to the end value of the car in the given lane.

"car0blue": since this is the first car it is assigned to lane 0.

```
{"name": "car0blue", "start": 0, "end": 3, "lane": 0}
```

"car1red": since it won't fit into lane 0 it's assigned to lane 1.

```
{"name": "car0blue", "start": 0, "end": 3, "lane": 0},
{"name": "car1red", "start": 1, "end": 4, "lane": 1},
```

"car2yellow": since it will fit into lane 0 it's assigned to lane 0.

```
{"name": "car0blue", "start": 0, "end": 3, "lane": 0},
{"name": "car1red", "start": 1, "end": 4, "lane": 1},
{"name": "car2yellow", "start": 3, "end": 7, "lane":0},
```

"car3green": since it won't fit into lane 0 or lane 1 it's assigned to lane 2.

```
{"name": "car0blue", "start": 0, "end": 3, "lane": 0},
{"name": "car1red", "start": 1, "end": 4, "lane": 1},
{"name": "car2yellow", "start": 3, "end": 7, "lane": 0},
{"name": "car3green", "start": 3, "end": 6, "lane": 2},
```

"car4purple": since it won't fit into lane 0 but will fit into lane 1 it's assigned to lane 1.

```
{"name": "car0blue", "start": 0, "end": 3, "lane": 0},
{"name": "car1red", "start": 1, "end": 4, "lane": 1},
{"name": "car2yellow", "start": 3, "end": 7, "lane": 0},
{"name": "car3green", "start": 3, "end": 6, "lane": 2},
{"name": "car4purple", "start": 4, "end": 7, "lane": 1},
```

"car5grey": since it won't fit into lane 0, lane 1 or lane 2 it's assigned to lane 3

```
{"name": "car0blue", "start": 0, "end": 3, "lane": 0},
{"name": "car1red", "start": 1, "end": 4, "lane": 1},
{"name": "car2yellow", "start": 3, "end": 7, "lane": 0},
{"name": "car3green", "start": 3, "end": 6, "lane": 2},
{"name": "car4purple", "start": 4, "end": 7, "lane": 1},
{"name": "car5grey", "start": 5, "end": 11, "lane": 3},
```

**What I've tried**

I figured I would need some sort of array containing the current end values of each lane to compare against but realize I'm stuck and looking for some help.

```
      var laneBuffer = [];

      cars.forEach((item, i) => {
        if (i === 0) {
          item.lane = 0;
          laneBuffer.push(item);
        }
        else{
          //Brain freeze...
          });
        }
      });
```

Comment: Are your cars always aligned to the grid? Does that mean `start` and `end` are always whole numbers?

Comment: Also, do you have an infinite number of lanes? If no, what happens to cars that don't fit in lane 0 through 3?

Comment: What is the minimum value for `start` and what is the maximum value for `end`?

Comment: @soimon Start and end are always whole numbers and there can be infinite number of lanes.

Comment: @trincot The minimum value for start is 0 and maximum value of end is infinite

Comment: OK, and the number of cars?

Comment: @trincot There is no maximum for the number of cars either. It should be able to take an array of basically any length and assign the lanes. In this particular case I'm dealing with a couple hundered cars that seem to fill up about 20 lanes.

Comment: Is `car.start == car.end` possible?

Comment: @trincot, no, car.end > car.start

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fun problem. This algorithm should work in all cases.

```js
const cars = [
    { name: "car0blue", start: 0, end: 3 },
    { name: "car1red", start: 1, end: 4 },
    { name: "car2yellow", start: 3, end: 7 },
    { name: "car3green", start: 3, end: 6 },
    { name: "car4purple", start: 4, end: 7 },
    { name: "car5grey", start: 5, end: 11 },
];

const lanes = [];
cars.forEach(placeInFreeLane);
console.log( cars );

// Algorithm:

function placeInFreeLane(car) {
    let lane = 0;
    while (!tryFitInLane(car, lane)) lane++;
    car.lane = lane;
}

function tryFitInLane(car, laneNumber) {
    const lane = lanes[laneNumber];
    if (lane === undefined) {
        lanes[laneNumber] = [car];
        return true;
    } else {
        const intersectsWithAny = lane.some(otherCar => intersects(car, otherCar));
        if (!intersectsWithAny) {
            lane.push(car);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function intersects(a, b) { return a.start < b.end && a.end > b.start; }
```

Output given your case (matches the desired output):

```
[
  { "name": "car0blue", "start": 0, "end": 3, "lane": 0 },
  { "name": "car1red", "start": 1, "end": 4, "lane": 1 },
  { "name": "car2yellow", "start": 3, "end": 7, "lane": 0 },
  { "name": "car3green", "start": 3, "end": 6, "lane": 2 },
  { "name": "car4purple", "start": 4, "end": 7, "lane": 1 },
  { "name": "car5grey", "start": 5, "end": 11, "lane": 3 }
]
```

---

**EDIT:** for the fun of it here is another version written in a more functional manner. This one is self contained and doesn't mutate the original or global state. It copies the input data and has no side effects.

```js
// Algorithm:

const intersects = (a, b) => a.start < b.end && a.end > b.start;
const hasNoIntersectionsWith = (car) => (lane) => !lane.some((other) => intersects(car, other));
const getPacked = (cars) => {
    const lanes = [];
    return cars.map((car) => {
        let freeLaneIndex = lanes.findIndex(hasNoIntersectionsWith(car));
        if (freeLaneIndex < 0) freeLaneIndex = lanes.push([]) - 1;
        lanes[freeLaneIndex].push(car);
        return { ...car, lane: freeLaneIndex };
    });
};

// Example:

var cars = [
    { name: "car0blue", start: 0, end: 3 },
    { name: "car1red", start: 1, end: 4 },
    { name: "car2yellow", start: 3, end: 7 },
    { name: "car3green", start: 3, end: 6 },
    { name: "car4purple", start: 4, end: 7 },
    { name: "car5grey", start: 5, end: 11 },
];

console.log(getPacked(cars));
```

Comment: Tested on a couple of scenarios and it works like a clock!

Comment: @MasterSmack That's great! I updated it with a functional version (shorter and doesn't mutate anything).

Comment: Great alternative solution! I'm new to arrow functions so next step is sitting down trying to understand exactly how it works :)

Comment: They are pretty similar to regular functions, so don't let the crazy syntax like `const hasNoIntersectionsWith = (car) => (lane) =>` confuse you. It just means that `hasNoIntersectionsWith(car)` returns another `function(lane)` which then get called in `lanes.findIndex`. The short syntax allows you to compose functions like this together really easily, it's fun to get into :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check each lane if the last `end` is smaller or equal to the current car `start`.

If you find a lane then you can add the car, if not you create a new lane.

```js
var cars = [
  {"name": "car0blue", "start": 0, "end": 3},
  {"name": "car1red", "start": 1, "end": 4},
  {"name": "car2yellow", "start": 3, "end": 7},
  {"name": "car3green", "start": 3, "end": 6},
  {"name": "car4purple", "start": 4, "end": 7},
  {"name": "car5grey", "start": 5, "end": 11},
]

const carLanes = [];

cars.forEach(car=>{
  const availableLane = carLanes.find(lane=>
    lane[lane.length-1].end <= car.start
  );
  if (availableLane) {
    availableLane.push(car);
  } else {
    carLanes.push([car]);
  }
})

console.log(carLanes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `cars` into `lanes` e.g.

```
[ car0
  car1
  car2
  car3
  car4
  car5
]
```

```
[ [car0, car2] // lane 0
  [car1, car4] // lane 1
  [car3]       // lane 2
  [car5]       // lane 3
]
```

This allows us to find a free lane simply by checking the last car of each lane. When you add a car to a lane, add the lane number to the car. Once you're done doing that flatten `lanes`:

```js
const assign_cars = cars => {
  const lanes = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i += 1) {
    const car = cars[i];
    const idx = lanes.findIndex(lane => lane[lane.length-1].end <= car.start);
    const free = idx > -1;
    const lane = free ? idx : lanes.length;
    if (free) lanes[lane].push({...car, lane});
    else lanes.push([{...car, lane}]);
  }
  return lanes.flat();
}

console.log(assign_cars(cars));
```

```html
<script>
const cars = [
  {"name": "car0blue", "start": 0, "end": 3},
  {"name": "car1red", "start": 1, "end": 4},
  {"name": "car2yellow", "start": 3, "end": 7},
  {"name": "car3green", "start": 3, "end": 6},
  {"name": "car4purple", "start": 4, "end": 7},
  {"name": "car5grey", "start": 5, "end": 11},
]
</script>
```